# .NET - c# - Cross partition query is required but disabled trouble on Document data access

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have written the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkdyC.png) code to fetch a record from the DocumentClient.
It is showing the following error on the code line:

```
return await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), item);
```

Comment: Can you show us the error message and the stack trace?

Comment: You can refer to my demo to see if it is useful or suggestive for your question. Suggestions can provide more useful information and look forward to your reply.

Comment: Ok sorry for that but im gonna re-write again

Comment: @AdvisorMagwaza What do you mean? What specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: When i want to add a new student